# How do I get Python turtle to recognize when I click the background?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a game where you click a bunch of random circles and get a score, however I also want it to deduct from your score when you miss the circle. I've been trying to use `screen.onclick()` but instead of deducting the score on a misclick it seems to deduct the score every second for no reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
import turtle
from random import random, randint
import time

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
score=0

def addscore():
    global score
    score += 1

def deletescore():
    global score
    score -= 1

def my_circle(color):

    radius = (15)

    circle = turtle.Turtle('circle', visible=False)
    circle.shapesize(radius / CURSOR_SIZE)
    circle.color(color)
    circle.penup()

    while True:
        nx = randint(2 * radius - width // 2, width // 2 - radius * 2)
        ny = randint(2 * radius - height // 2, height // 2 - radius * 2)

        circle.goto(nx, ny)

        for other_radius, other_circle in circles:
            if circle.distance(other_circle) < 2 * max(radius, other_radius):
                break
        else:
            break

    circle.showturtle()
    circle.onclick(lambda x,y,t=circle: (circle.hideturtle(), addscore()))
    screen.onclick(deletescore())


    return radius, circle

username=str(input("Set your username: "))

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("lightgreen")
screen.title("Speed Clicker")

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

circles = []

gameLength = 30
difficulty = 20
startTime = time.time()
while True:
    time.sleep(1/difficulty)

    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    timeTaken = time.time() - startTime

    circles.append(my_circle(rgb))
    screen.title('SCORE: {}, TIME LEFT: {}'.format(score,int(round(gameLength - timeTaken,0))))

    if time.time() - startTime > gameLength: 
        break

screen.title('GG! FINAL SCORE: {}'.format(score))


screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
screen.onclick(deletescore())
```

It's in the wrong place (only needs to be called once, not in a loop) and the argument is incorrect, it should be passing the function not calling it:

```
screen.onclick(deletescore)
```

The fix is multifold: first, move the modified statement to just before your `while True:` statement.  Then fix the definition of `deletescore()` to take `x` and `y` arguments that we won't use but are necessary to be a click handler.  (Or wrap it in a `lambda` like the call to `addscore()`)

However, a click on a turtle can also be passed through as a click on the screen.  To counter this, we can add 2 in `addscore()` instead of 1 since `deletescore()` will get called as well.  That should be enough to get things working.

However, we really should eliminate the `while True:` loop and `sleep()` call which have no place in an event-driven program.  Instead we use `ontimer()` to keep things moving and not potentially block other events.  The reformulated code would be more like:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import random, randint
from time import time

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def addscore():
    global score
    score += 2  # add 2 as this will also count as a -1 screen click!

def deletescore():
    global score
    score -= 1

def my_circle(color):

    circle = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
    circle.shapesize(radius / CURSOR_SIZE)
    circle.color(color)
    circle.penup()

    while True:
        nx = randint(2 * radius - width // 2, width // 2 - radius * 2)
        ny = randint(2 * radius - height // 2, height // 2 - radius * 2)

        circle.goto(nx, ny)

        for other_radius, other_circle in circles:
            if circle.distance(other_circle) < 2 * max(radius, other_radius):
                break
        else:
            break

    circle.onclick(lambda x, y: (circle.hideturtle(), addscore()))
    circle.showturtle()

    return radius, circle

def play():
    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    timeTaken = time() - startTime

    circles.append(my_circle(rgb))

    screen.title('SCORE: {}, TIME LEFT: {}'.format(score, int(round(gameLength - timeTaken, 0))))

    if time() - startTime > gameLength:
        screen.title('FINAL SCORE: {}'.format(score))
        screen.onclick(None)
        screen.clear()
    else:
        screen.ontimer(play, 1000 // difficulty)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("lightgreen")
screen.title("Speed Clicker")

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

score = 0

circles = []

radius = 15
difficulty = 20
gameLength = 30

screen.onclick(lambda x, y: deletescore())

startTime = time()

play()

screen.mainloop()
```